# Readable way to select child on an iterated array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have a table with tr's and in every row I have td's. I want to use jquery selector to select the third child. I know I can do something ugly like "$($(d).children()[3]);", but I prefer using 'eq' instead, or at least something more readable.

Right now it looks like this:

```
 _.each($('tr'), function(d,i){
                var td = $($(d).children()[3]);
                .
                .
                rest of my code...
            })
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$.each( $('tr'), function(d,i) {
    $(this).find('td:eq(2)');
});
```

Note that the first child is `eq(0)`, so the third is `eq(2)`

As alternative you can use this selector:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(3)')
```

Comment: and can I do something like: if($('tr td:nth-child(3)').text() == "blabla"){...   and it will iterate on the array (if it is one)?

Comment: You could use `$("tr td:nth-child(3):contains('blabla')")`. This will select all table cells that contain the text "blabla". If you only want to know if there exists a cell that contains "blabla" you use `$("tr td:nth-child(3):contains('blabla')").length`, this gives the number of cells (or null if none)